# Get all the services of the current day on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a query to get all `servicios` of specific `motoboy` but I need that they are of the current day. The data type of that attribute is `timestamp`. I have this code but doenst work

```
Motoboy::with(array('servicios' => function($query){
                    $query->where('id_estado', '1')->orWhere('id_estado', '2')
                    ->where('fecha_hora', new DateTime('today'));

                }))->where('auth_token',$auth)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Date should be passed as a string date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()'). Use mysql Between to get the data between the two timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new DateTime` is instantiating an object and does not have the the format you need for `timestamp`.
A simple solution is to use the `date()` function to specify the format you want, so for the current `timestamp` you would use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Also, I would recommend that you query the entire day like this:

```
$startToday = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
$endToday = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
// ...
->whereBetween('fecha_hora', array($startToday,$endToday));
// ....
```

Your code would turn into this:

```
Motoboy::with(array('servicios' => function($query){
    $startToday = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
    $endToday = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
    $query->where('id_estado', '1')->orWhere('id_estado', '2')->whereBetween('fecha_hora', array($startToday,$endToday));

}))->where('auth_token',$auth)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: return a service with this hora.. ``"fecha_hora": "2019-02-08 05:02:00",``